# "A month passed" or “A month past”?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, time, past-participles

I recently wrote the sentence, "I saw the deadline was a month passed," and have confused myself over whether it should be *past* or *passed*.

I believe it is *passed*—perhaps as an adverbial past participle?—because I am not referring to the *past month*, specifically, but that *a month has passed*. Also, if I take out "a month" I am left with, "I saw the deadline was passed" which I believe is more the meaning I seek (even if awkward) than "I saw the deadline was past". I am not confident, though.

Potentially relevant previous questions:

1. ["Past due" or "passed due"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102459/past-due-or-passed-due)
2. [date has already passed OR date has already past?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192313/date-has-already-passed-or-date-has-already-past) — This question, though, is simply a matter of the poster not knowing the meanings of *past* and *passed*, and was closed.

Comment: General reference. M-W, for instance,  gives 'ago' as a synonym for 'past' in the sense used in 'I saw the deadline was a month past' ['started working on this project 10 years past']. It does miscategorise this usage as 'adjective' ('past' is actually a postposition here)..

Comment: Closed for general reference three years after being asked and disagreeing answers? What does this gain?

Comment: It is requested at the Help Center that both questions and answers contain evidence of reasonable research / linked and attributed supporting references. But no such research is shown. The M-W examples essentially explain the usage. Closing the question is an attempt to discourage similarly inappropriate posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the sentence is incorrect with **passed**. It would say that the **deadline** was **a month passed**, but the deadline does not equate in any obvious way to **a month passed**. It does seem, however, that one could say that the deadline was **a month past**, if one considers **a month past** equivalent to **a month ago**. Colloquially, that would locate the deadline in time, which is acceptable.

So, the answer to your question is:

> "I saw the deadline was a month past."

A few obvious ways to avoid the problem:

- I saw that the deadline *had* **passed**. (not *was*)
- I saw that the deadline had **passed** a month ago.
- I saw that I was one month **past** the deadline.
- I saw that I was **past** the deadline by a month.

If I try to stay as close as possible to your structure:

- I saw that the deadline *had been* one month *exceeded*.
- I saw that the deadline *had been exceeded* by one month.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow your logic for it seems you are claiming the invalidity if all non-tautological statements. Would you then also say that we could not say "The deadline was a month gone-by" or "The deadline was a month ago" or even "The deadline was yesterday"? Could you please expand upon your reasoning?

Comment: @Unrelated I didn't intend to claim that, so I may need to refine my answer. Your 2nd and 3rd examples here are fine, because they're statements about where the deadline is located in time: colloquially, I can equate "deadline" to "a month ago" or "yesterday". In your original example, I wouldn't have objected to "The deadline was a month (or a day) ago."  I do object to replacing "ago" with "passed" or "past", but I don't have the command of grammatical terminology necessary to explain why. I have a similar issue with "a month gone-by" -- it doesn't mean the same thing to me as "a month ago".

Comment: @Unrelated I revised my answer based on our exchange. Thanks for engaging.

Comment: @Unrelated With new thinking in hand, "a month gone-by" seems fine if one considers it equivalent to "a month ago". It locates the deadline in time.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a month past with *due* being implied. Otherwise you'd need to make it more clear that the deadline had been passed, like the 'deadline had been passed'.

I understand what you mean and it could be considered correct but it's ambiguous. The deadline was passed by a month is what you mean, but you're setting the operative word in a place that begs interpretation even if the result is the same.

I understand your thinking, but a better option would be "the deadline was a month exceeded".

Comment: What if I were to use a different noun than deadline though? The celebration was a month past?

Comment: @Unrelated, Your original statement works, but with respect to expectations in time past is more clear. The time for you to return the letter is past. The conversation is a month passed.  The moment I raised the ante was 3 minutes passed. It's just a little awkward.

Comment: "The celebration was a month past" is incorrect for reasons I provided in my answer. You could make any number of other statements that are correct: "The celebration took place a month ago." We are one month past the celebration." "One month has passed since the celebration." Et cetera.

Comment: @John You're kidding, right?

Comment: @RichardKayser, of course. What are _you_ talking about?

Comment: @John The time for you to return the letter has passed, not past.

Comment: @RichardKayser, amazingly bad on my part. Thank you. It's past my bedtime. :)

Comment: @John I get it. It's late here in Maryland, but ELU SE is addictive. Have a good night.

Comment: With new thinking in hand, "The celebration was a month past" is fine if one considers "a month past" equivalent to "a month ago". Colloquially, it simply locates the celebration in time.